# Удалить слова, совпадающие с первым словом списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
s = "way, week, man, woman, area, study, way, book, eye, side, house, way, local."
s = s.split()
z = s[0]
for i in s:
    y = s.index(z)
    del s[y]
    print(*s)
```

Хочется чтобы выводило только 3 рядок или без ошыбки "Traceback (most recent call last): ..." [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если сделать код такой, чтобы вывело только один раз список, но уже изменненый:

```
s = "way, week, man, woman, area, study, way, book, eye, side, house, way, local."
s = s.split()
z = s[0]
for i in s:
    y = s.index(z)
    del s[y]
print(*s)
```

Выбивает новую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть предложение как исправить одну из этих ошибок, но главное минимально поменять существующий код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = "way, week, man, woman, area, study, way, book, eye, side, house, way, local."
wordToDelete = s.split(', ')[0]
s = s.replace(wordToDelete, '')[2:].replace(', , ', ', ')
```

Comment: с первой запятой проблема :)

Comment: @Zhihar edited ;)

Comment: `week, man, woman, area, study, , book, eye, side, house, , local.` уверены? ;-)

Comment: У меня две лишних запятых, как их забрать?

Comment: @P1CA5S0 edited ;)

Comment: а вот и нет `week, man, woman, area, studybook, eye, side, houselocal.` - смотрите на последнее слово :)

Comment: @Zhihar Все. Я отупел по полной ;)  edited

Comment: 5 слово тоже с ошибкой

Comment: @P1CA5S0 Принимать надо не все что попало, а тот ответ, что тебе лучше всего помог. Голос "принять" (галочка) можно поставить только на одном ответе.

Comment: опять не то - посмотрите что будет со строкой `s = "way, way, week, man, woman, area, study, way, book, eye, side, house, way, local, way."`

Comment: @P1CA5S0, не ведитесь на контрафакт, мой алгоритм работает надежно как часы :)))

Comment: @Zhihar ;D.....

Answer (score 2):

например так:

```
s = "way, week, man, woman, area, study, way, book, eye, side, house, way, local."
words = s.split(', ')
s = ', '.join(filter(lambda word: word != words[0], words))
```

сбой происходит если последнее слово и первое одинаковое

можно исправить так:

```
s = "way, week, man, woman, area, study, way, book, eye, side, house, way, local, way."
words = s.split(', ')
s = ', '.join(filter(lambda word: word != words[0], words))
s = s.replace(words[0], '')
s = s.replace(', .', '.')
```

но это все таки костылинг

если точно в конце предложения ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНА, тогда можно вот так сделать:

```
s = "way, week, man, woman, area, study, way, book, eye, side, house, way, local, way."
words = s[:-1].split(', ')
s = ', '.join(filter(lambda word: word != words[0], words)) + '.'
```